# Creating equal price bins based on quantile pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
id    value    price
1      abc     10
2      bcn     20
...    ...     ...
100    qwe      35
```

i want to get my results in similar format as shown below.
such that for every quantile it gives me how many rows(id's) are there.

for eg,in the quantile 0.2 the price is `8.0` , so the `no_of_rows` should contain id's whose product lies between `0-8`.

Similarly for `quantile 0.4` , the `price is 11.0`, so i want to know how many id's are there which is `greater than 8.0 and <=11.0` 
and so on

i'e for

and what rows are there (based on train_id in list as shown below)

column `0` refers to price

```
                  0    No_of_rows  ids
('price', 0.2)   8.0      20       [1,2,6,9] 
('price', 0.4)   11.0     23       [7,8,22,90]      #(dummy values for representation
('price', 0.6)   14.0     11       [13,29,61,98] 
('price', 0.8)   20.0     33       [18,20,61,29] 
('price', 0.95)  35.0     10       [71,23,16,59] 
('price', 0.99)  66.0      5       ... 
('price', 1.0)   167.0     2       ...
```

I tried this:

```
quantile = df[['price']].quantile([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.95,0.99,1]).unstack()
```

which gave me this result

```
                  0    
 ('price', 0.2)   8.0     
 ('price', 0.4)  11.0     
 ('price', 0.6)  14.0     
 ('price', 0.8)  20.0     
 ('price', 0.95) 35.0     
 ('price', 0.99) 66.0      
 ('price', 1.0)  167.0
```

How can i bring in the two required column's `No_of_rows  ids`

Because after getting the no. of rows, i want to bin the products into **high, medium, and low priced** (haven't thought on the best logic yet)

But if i get the required dataframe i can think of one.

Comment: Does [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) do what you need? Maybe followed by a `groupby(...).count()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add first `0` quantile to [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) and then use `groupby` with `size`:

```
q =  [0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.95,0.99,1]
a = df.groupby(pd.qcut(df['price'], q=q, labels=q[1:])).size()
print (a)

price
0.20    1
0.40    0
0.60    1
0.80    0
0.95    0
0.99    0
1.00    1
dtype: int64
```